# How to sort list in groovy

Tags: groovy

i'm try to sort array list

eg.

```
def list = [1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1]
```

hope to sort :

```
[1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3]
```

Thank you very much.

---

i'm used to my code

eg.

```
def plnProcessGoalInstance = ......someting    
def order = plnProcessGoalInstance.plnGoal.plnTargetPlan.id.unique() //[1, 4, 3,] ,plnProcessGoalInstance.plnGoal.plnTargetPlan.id = [1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1]
def plnProcessGoalInstance = plnProcessGoalInstance.sort{ a, b -> 
           order.indexOf(a.plnGoal.plnTargetPlan.id ) <=> order.indexOf(b.plnGoal.plnTargetPlan.id )}
```

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: You want to sort it with 3 at the end?  Can you describe how your sort is supposed to work?

Comment: Looks like you want to sort based on:
A. Occurrences of certain number (Descending)
B. Number (Ascending)

Comment: [1,2,3,4,1] -> [1,1,2,3,4]
[1,4,3,2,1] -> [1,1,4,3,2] it's same groupBy

Comment: @Deruijter nice guess... looks like you were right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
def order = [ 1, 4, 3 ]
def list = [ 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1 ]

list.sort { a, b -> order.indexOf( a ) <=> order.indexOf( b ) }

assert list == [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 3]
```

Or, assuming the comment by Deruijter is correct and you want to sort by descending frequency and then by number for those with the same freq:

```
def list = [ 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1 ]
def order = list.countBy { it }
                .sort { a, b -> 
                  b.value <=> a.value ?: a.key <=> b.key
                }.keySet().toList()
list.sort { a, b -> order.indexOf( a ) <=> order.indexOf( b ) }
```

`countBy` requires Groovy 1.8